# Chaining dependencies from submake to its parent

Tags: get, makefile, dependencies, call

I made a small example to illustrate my issue:

I have several projects and one principal Makefile to rule them all.

```
/+
 |+ Makefile
 |+ Project A
 |  + Makefile
 |+ Project B
 |  + Makefile 
 |...
```

The parent `Makefile` looks like this:

```
DUMMY := $(shell $(MAKE) -C a deps) $(shell $(MAKE) -C b deps)

.PHONY: all clean

all: out.zip
    @echo Operation Done!

a/a.zip: $(addprefix a/,$(shell cat a/deps))
    $(MAKE) -C a $(notdir $@)

b/b.zip: $(addprefix b/,$(shell cat b/deps))
    $(MAKE) -C b $(notdir $@)

out.zip: a/a.zip b/b.zip
    zip $@ $^ 

clean: 
    $(MAKE) -C a clean
    $(MAKE) -C b clean
```

And here one of the sub-makefile (inside each sub-projects):

```
C   = $(notdir $(shell pwd))
SRC = $(addsuffix .c, $(addprefix $(C), 1 2 3 4))
OBJ = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRC))

all: $(C).zip 

$(SRC): %.c : 
    touch $@

$(OBJ): %.o : %.c  
    cp $< $@

$(C).zip: $(OBJ)
    zip $@ $^

clean: 
    -rm -f *.o *.zip deps
    $(MAKE) $(SRC)
deps: 
    @echo $(SRC) > $@

.PHONY: all clean deps
```

My question is quite simple: How to avoid calling the sub-makefile in order to get all the dependancies. Indeed, when I modify one of the source file inside a sub-project, the main Makefile is unable to know whether or not the target needs to be rebuilt.

I also found that I can call make with the options `$(MAKE) -C<dir> -n -s` which allow me to write my rules like this:

```
a/a.zip: $(if $(shell make -C a -n -s), $(shell rm a/a.zip),)
    $(MAKE) -C a $(notdir $@)

b/b.zip: $(if $(shell make -C b -n -s), $(shell rm b/b.zip),)
    $(MAKE) -C b $(notdir $@)
```

But I'm sure this is not the best solution !

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Of course I could use a macro `get_deps = $(shell $(MAKE) -C $(1) deps >NUL) $(addprefix $(1)/,$(shell cat $(1)/deps))` and calling it like `a/a.zip: $(call, getdeps, a)`. But I don't know if it's better not not...

Comment: Can you edit all the Makefiles? Or are the subprojects 3rd party libraries?

Comment: Yes I can edit all of them but I would like to allow them to work in standalone without any dependances to their parent. Perhaps the option `make --question` can be useful as well but I still don't know how I can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share your subprojects sources, **$(SRCPRJ1)** and **$(SRCPRJ2)**, in another file (a config file) that would be loaded by the principal Makefile too. Or just redo them in the principal, instead.

After that, put them as the prerequisites of your targets in the principal Makefile:

```
a/a.zip: $(SRCPRJ1)
    $(MAKE) -C a $(notdir $@)

b/b.zip: $(SRCPRJ2)
    $(MAKE) -C b $(notdir $@)
```

Thus, the recipes a/a.zip and b/b.zip will only be parsed if its dependencies have been updated.

That worked to me.

Comment: coin, the answer was useful? if yes, accept it, please.

Comment: sorry your answer was useful but not exactly what I was looking for.